# DRY way to define multiple virtual attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I'm writing an app that acts as a tailor measure form.

The customers model has a lot of attributes that are stored in the database as integers in millimeters.
Since this app will be used both in Europe and in the US I'll use virtual attributes for showing the user a inches and a centimeter version of the data.

For example for the customer height I have this in my model:

```
  def height_in_cm
    height / 10
  end

  def height_in_cm=(height)
    self.height = height.to_f  * 10
  end

  def height_in_in
    height * 0.039370
  end

  def height_in_in=(height)
    self.height = height.to_f / 0.039370
  end
```

And this in my _form view:

```
  <% if @customer.measure_unit.eql? "imperial" %>
    <%= f.input :height_in_in %></br>
  <% else %>      
    <% if @customer.measure_unit.eql? "metric" %>
      <%= f.input :height_in_cm %></br>
    <% end %>     
  <% end %>
```

Since as I said I have many attributes my customer model file is becoming extremely long and very error prone.

Is there a dry way to shorten it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate that logic something like this:

```
def display_height
  case measure_unit
  when 'imperial' then height_in_in
  when 'metric'   then height_in_cm
  else height_in_in
  end
end
```

Then your view can just be like this:

```
<%= @customer.display_height %>
```

If you are using these same conversion methods in lots of models, extract it out to a module like so:

```
module HeightConversions

  def height_in_cm
    height / 10
  end

  def height_in_in
    height * 0.039370
  end

  def display_height
    case measure_unit
    when 'imperial' then height_in_in
    when 'metric'   then height_in_cm
    else height_in_in
    end
  end

end
```

And include it like so in the models where needed:

```
class Customer
  include HeightConversions
end
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, perhaps you need something more like this:

```
  %w(neck waist arm).each do |name|
    self.class_eval do

      define_method :"#{name}_in_cm" do
        self.send(name) / 10
      end

      define_method :"#{name}_in_cm=" do |n|
        self.send("#{name}=", (n.to_f * 10))
      end

      define_method :"#{name}_in_in" do
        self.send(name) * 0.03
      end

      define_method :"#{name}_in_in=" do |n|
        self.send("#{name}=", (n.to_f / 0.039370))
      end

    end
  end
```

This is usually called *metaprogramming*. Here's a nice concise article on different ways to do it in Rails:
http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but probably my question was not clear. My problem is that my model has many attributes and in my model I have to define the virtual attributes for each one. The snippet I posted was for the height attribute but I have many more: neck_circonference, sleeve_lenght, waist_circumference, bust_circumference etc...

Comment: This looks great. It just works but I need to study it a little bit since I don't understand it all. Also using this example I need to preassign a value for each attribute (even zero) otherwise in the first create action it tells me that cannot do operations on nil class. Assigning zeros prevents me from adding a feature that tells the user what percentage of the form he has completed. Anyway this is the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would let either a gem or javascript do the conversion. A gem such as [ruby-units](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-units) might be overkill but provides a lasting solution for any conversion you could want.

For letting javascript do the conversion, here's something you could add to your application.js. You could also use the "baseline" concept to DRY your method in rails.

```
function convert_units(input, input_unit, output_unit) {
// Used to convert all units to similar intermediary unit. I used meters.
var inches_per_meter = 39.3701;
var sixteenths_per_meter = 629.9216;
var cm_per_meter = 100;
var mm_per_meter = 1000;

var intermediary = 0; //in meters

switch(input_unit)
{
  case: "mm": intermediary = input * mm_per_meter;
    break;
  case: "cm": intermediary = input * cm_per_meter;
    break;
  case: "meter": intermediary = input;
    break;
  case: "inches": intermediary = input * inches_per_meter;
    break;
  case: "sixteenths": intermediary = input * sixteenths_per_meter;
    break;
  default: return "Input unit not correctly accomodated";
}

switch(output_unit)
{
  case: "mm": return intermediary / mm_per_meter;
    break;
  case: "meter": return intermediary;
    break;
  case: "inches": return intermediary / inches_per_meter;
    break;
  case: "sixteenths": return intermediary / sixteenths_per_meter;
    break;
  case: "cm": return intermediary / cm_per_meter;
    break;
  default: return "Output unit not correctly accomodated";
}
}
```

Then in your views

```
convert_units(@customer.height, 'inches', 'cm');
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach looks interesting but since my knowledge of js is very limited I prefer a more railish approach. This will make my code easier to maintain. Also I looked into ruby-units before. This gem does what it says and provides a great precision on conversions. Anyway it stores my data in strings (such as "23 cm") instead of integers and this in the long term might become a problem if I need to operate directly on the db.